# Wordpress 3 parent pages are showing posts not their page content

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress 3.6.1 site at: [http://ileap.org](http://ileap.org/)

My top level pages (except the home page ) are showing posts not their given page content.  In the backend the content is right.  The weird thing is that the child pages work fine.  Clicking around the nav to any child page you get the appropriate content, its just the parents.  Permalinks are set to just Post Name, and I have changed the setting saved and then reset to make sure its not that.

This has stumped me for 2 days now.  any ideas?

I am running the metrovibes theme.

I also tried changing the theme back to 2013 and that did not solve it.

thanks

Comment: check the pages used template, if the wrong template is set, you will face the exact issue you are facing now

Answer (score 0):

Every page in `Wordpress` executes from `page.php` (If it is not customized as per your HTML).

There are two ways to get the content of page.

**First:**

```
the_content();
```

**Second:**

```
global $post;
echo $post->post_content;
```